# Reading data from hard drive and put it in a c++ container

Tags: c++, file-io, wav, binaryfiles, hard-drive

I wrote a simple thread and its task is just to read the data from hard drive , put it in a container and tag it with timestamp and an unique Id. After that I will write the newly structured data into a memory mapped file.

The thing is I don't care about the internal structure of the data, I mean it can be in a Wav format (because in the real situtaion I will be dealing with some audio datas which are avergely 3 mb each) bu I won't do any operaions on that data. After inserting it in my struct I will be just dealing with the UniqueId and Data Tag. Sample structure would be something like:

```
Struct SampleData 
{
long UniqueID;
...  MyData; // the data which I am trying to read from hard drive
Time  insertionTime;
}
```

So the question is how am i going to read a Wav data into this struct without knowing (because i don't need to) the internal structure of it? What will ve the `...` part for instance. Is there any container type for a large data chunk?

For reading tha data may I use `ifstream` or any other method?

Comment: Why do you want to read the data in if you "won't do any operations" on that data in the first place. You can store the raw bytes in e.g. a `char[]`.

Comment: The file will work as a data buffer. So the data is going to come without any tags, I will add uniqueId and insertionTime tags to it and put it in a file on disk. Some reader applications are going to make some search operations on them (with the tags not data itself) and I will going to send the requested data to these Reader applications.

Comment: Can you not just add the tags to the existing file? I know not your question ...

Comment: what do you mean by "existing file"? There is no existing file actually the data will be send by a writer application. But for the test purpose I'm trying to read it from harddirve by a thread (just to simulate Writer applications job). So in the real situtaion the data without tags will be send from another application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to keep it in a TLV format:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value

EDIT:
A very simple container for TLV.

You'll be able to store the raw data as it is and you'll know which field you're reading and what's its size.

```
class TlvContainer
{
public:
  unsigned long Type; // Maybe we have billions of types of objects?
  unsigned long Size; // The size of the object.
  unsigned char* Bytes; // This will hold the raw data.
};
```

When you write your data to the file, you'll have to know how many bytes it is, allocate the "Bytes" array and update the "Size" field.
When you read it from the file, you'll know how you have written it in. (You'll have to read the fields in the same order you have written them.)

For example, if you wrote it as: Type, Size, Bytes:
You'll first read sizeof(unsigned long) from the file to know the the type of the element.
Then you'll need to read another sizeof(unsigned long) to know how big is your real data.
and then you'll be able to read "Size" bytes from the file, knowing that after them there is a new element built the same way.

Comment: it seems nice, but for the size it is written something like "(typically 1-4 bytes)". Will it work for 4MB file? And is it possible to put an audio file into this container, if yes how? Do you know any sample code or something? Thank you.

Comment: The sizes of the type and size fields are up to you. If you have 512 types of objects, 1 byte for the "type" field won't be enough to represent all of them, so it's perfectly ok to use 2 bytes. use as much bytes as you need for it.

Comment: Actually I have only one type of fixed size data. I mean the writer application will send same type data 4 times in 1 second. So it will be a fixed type data stream. I'm just trying to simulate this stream so I wrote a thread to do the job 4 times in 1 second but I was just wondering how can I simulate the data. So the best fit can be a WAV file because in the real situation the data that is send by the Writer App will be audio as well. So for my case is it ok to use TLV container? And how can I put an WAV data (or any other format) into TLV?

Comment: If you have only 1 type, you can omit the "type" field from the structure but I wouldn't. it is a better idea to make it only 1 byte having the same value. It will be more scalable this way.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. What do you think about the performance, do you think it can fit the requirement for 4 packages in 1 second? By the way to be able to read the data into this structure again I may use ifstream right? or is there any other way?

Comment: The overhead of the TLV fields will be about 5 bytes. Compared to the overall size of the data in your package, it shouldn't make a difference. I think you'll be fine. There are several ways to read from a file. As long you are doing correctly you can do it any way you want.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing MyData as `vector<unsigned char>`?

You can use file streams to read but remember to use ios::binary mode. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Here is sample code. You may want to add error checking. Also, I didn't try to compile this so there may be mistakes.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
ifstream file("sample.wav", ios::binary);
while(!file.eof()) {
    unsigned char byte;
    file >> byte;
    data.push_back(byte);
 }
```

Comment: In the tutorial it is reading the binary file from a file. Actually for my situtaion no need for that. For example I can put a 2MB WAV file into the projects folder and read it from there. But a wav or any other audio formatted data can be read into a vector<unsigned char>? Is it possible to do that with just  "ifstream" ?

Comment: I believe so. I was just referring that tutorial for the usage of ios::binary mode. I added example code that I haven't tested.

Comment: By the way, if you don't process the data, why store it at all? Will it be written somewhere later?

Comment: The file will work as a data buffer. So the data is going to come without any tags, I will add uniqueId and insertionTime tags to it and put it in a file on disk. Some reader applications are going to make some search operations on them (with the tags not data itself) and I will going to send the requested data to these Reader applications.

Comment: Thank you I will try this one, but i am suspicious about the performance. Because the writer app will send the data like 4 packages per second so to be able to simulate tihs in my thread I may read the data from the harddrive in this frequency as well. And may be it can be too costly, what do you think?

Comment: There are faster ways to read a file but I think this is one of the simplest and thus perfect for testing which it is for. If it isn't fast enought for your test, you can simply read all your samples into a datastructure at the start and send them magnitudes faster than you can read the disk.